# Removing container from wp_nav_menu not working

Tags: menus

I'm converting this html menu to wordpress:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/" class="current"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/"><span>About</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

i use:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
 'menu'=>'mainmenu' ,
 'container'       => false, 
 'link_before'     => '<span>',
 'link_after'      => '</span>',
 'theme_location'  => 'primary')
 );
```

but the html i get is:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/goodsoil/" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/goodsoil/?page_id=2" title="About"><span>About</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If i use a custom menu then i get:

```
<ul id="menu-test" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-6"><a href="url/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-5"><a href="url/?page_id=2"><span>About</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

but if i don't use a custom menu  'container'=>false doesn't work
Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by _if i don't use a custom menu_ ? Could you please describe more clearly under which conditions you get desired result and when not?

Comment: My theme supports custom menus.
If i use a custom menu the 'container'=>false works fine, but if not it doesn't works.
If i use 'container'=>'' happens the same.

Answer (score 19):

[SOLVED]
IT DOES NOT WORK when you are referring to an inexisting location. e.g. when you copied the code from somewhere else, or you haven't created your menu or location yet in the dasboard.

e.g. remove ", 'theme_location' => 'primary'" from the following code:

```
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container'=> false, 'menu_class'=> false, 'menu_id'=> 'ia_toplevel', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
```

so it shoult look like

```
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container'=> false, 'menu_class'=> false, 'menu_id'=> 'ia_toplevel' ) );
```

It works fine WITHOUT container in my website [SocialBlogsiteWebDesign.com](http://SocialBlogsiteWebDesign.com)

Comment: It seems not work in wordpress 3.9

Comment: Create your menu in the admin in `appearance->menu` first then call the `wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'<menu_name>','container'=>false))`

Comment: Well, that's a pretty odd behavior :/ I think this is an issue that should be tracked.

Comment: ... or don't remove it, and actually take a minute to create a menu location.

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution.

Simply use "ul" for 'container'

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
 'menu'=>'mainmenu' ,
 'container' => 'ul',
 'menu_class'=> '',
 'link_before'     => '<span>',
 'link_after'      => '</span>',
 'theme_location'  => 'primary')
 );
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for too, how to remove the unnecessary div from my nav menu!

Comment: Somehow this answer works but not empty string or `false`. Thanks.

Comment: this saved my life from a hell i tried all tuts all not working with latest versions this worked just exact as i want

Answer (score 5):

```
Try: <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '' ) ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: It is checked as `if ( $args->container )` in code so `false` or `empty string` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Rarst, I just tested it with a site I've been working on lately, and setting 'container' => '' did actually work. I think it's not testing for value, but more setting to null and thus not outputting data.

Comment: 'container' => '' doesn't work for me.
I'm using wp 3.0.1

Comment: doesnt work for me too ... with wp 3.2.1

Answer (score 5):

you are referring to the fallback function of the nav_menus. This is "wp_page_menu" and unfortunatelly it doesn't produce the same type of markup that a custom menu does.

To fix this create your own fallback menu. I'm using this:

```
function my_page_menu($args){
  $menu = '';
  $args['echo'] = false;
  $args['title_li'] = '';

  // If the front page is a page, add it to the exclude list
  if (get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') $args['exclude'] = get_option('page_on_front');

  $menu .= str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), '', wp_list_pages($args));

  if($menu):
    if($args['container']) $menu = '<'.$args['container'].' class="'.$args['container_class'].'">'.$menu;
    $menu .= '<ul class="'.$args['menu_class'].'">'.$menu;

    // add 'home' menu item
    $menu .= '<li class="home '.((is_front_page() && !is_paged()) ? 'current-menu-item' : null).'"><a href="'.home_url('/').'" title="'.__("Home Page").'">'.$args['link_before'].__("Home").$args['link_after'].'</a></li>';

    $menu .= '</ul>';
    if($args['container']) $menu .= '</'.$args['container'].'>\n"';
    $menu = apply_filters('wp_page_menu', $menu, $args);
  endif;

  echo $menu;
}
```

You might need to change this as my theme handles menus its own way, but I think you get the basic idea.

And when you're calling `wp_nav_menu` do it like `wp_nav_menu(array('fallback_cb' => 'my_page_menu'));`

You can also match the classes to the ones of a custom menu using this:

```
add_filter('page_css_class', 'atom_page_css_classes', 420, 2);
function atom_page_css_classes($classes, $page){
  // overwrite and use page (safe) name instead of ID; nobody styles IDs...
  $new_classes = array('page-'.$page->post_name);

  // adjust active menu classes to match the ones added by wp_nav_menu()
  foreach($classes as $class)
    if($class == 'current_page_item') $new_classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    elseif($class == 'current_page_parent') $new_classes[] = 'current-menu-parent';
    elseif($class == 'current_page_ancestor') $new_classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';

  return $new_classes;
}
```

This way you cut down a few CSS rules...

Answer (score 1):

I developed a simple and efficient solution using `str_replace`, which can be applied separately for use in menu tables rather than `ul li`:

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 
    'container_id' => 'mainMenu', 
    'container_class' => 'ddsmoothmenu',
    'echo' => FALSE
));

$menu = str_replace(
    array('ul id="main-menu" class="menu">','/ul>','li','/li>'), 
    array('table id="main-menu" class="menu">tr>','/tr>/table>','td','/td>'), 
    $menu
);

echo $menu;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as it will fail if there's ever any changes to the code the core spits out.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - use

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        // your menu id etc. goes here
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s', // removes the default <ul> 
        'container'  => '', // removes the outer <div>
    )
);
```

The default structure for `wp_nav_menu` with as few args as possible will be

```
<div class="menu-blahblah-container">
  <ul id="blahblah">
    <li class="menu-item">
    <li class="menu-item">
    <!-- etc -->
```

The `items_wrap` parameter defaults to `<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>` - so there's some fun easy ways there to manipulate things outside of what the question is here. But if you just want to totally remove that `ul` just change it to `%3$s` which basically means "all the stuff inside the ul; none of the ul."

So now we have:

```
<div class="menu-blahblah-container">
  <li class="menu-item">
  <li class="menu-item">
  <!-- etc -->
```

You're left with a bunch of `li`'s which is sweet! But they are trapped inside of a `div`, which is not sweet if you want to use them alongside some other custom `li`'s in your own nice little homebaked `ul`.

So now add in the `'container' => ''` bit others have suggested and you're home free: just the list items part of the menu with no container elements!

```
<li class="menu-item">
<li class="menu-item">
<!-- etc -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Menu','link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
```